# How to use the method "getFreeDragPosition" for Angular 8 CdkDrag?

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop

There is a method definition in Angular `CdkDrag` API.
[image]

But how to call it in code?

I have tried like below but error is happening. What is the right way to use this kind of methods?

```
export class DragableComponent implements OnInit {

  _dragRef: DragRef<CdkDrag>;


   this._dragRef.getFreeDragPosition();
```

Comment: Can you post the template for this component? It would help to know how are you using the [cdkDrag] directive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a method that is called on an instance of `CdkDrag`. One of the ways to get the instance is to use `cdkDragEnded` output event.

Sample code:

```js
public onDragEnded(event: CdkDragEnd): void {
  console.log(event.source.getFreeDragPosition()); // returns { x: 0, y: 0 }
}
```

```html
<p cdkDrag (cdkDragEnded)="onDragEnded($event)">
  Draggable paragraph
</p>
```

Comment: What is another way to get the instance? I need to use the "reset()" which is not connected to any output events.

Answer (score -1):

For anyone interested in how to use the "reset()" method, since its not comming naturaly from an event:

1. HTML: make a template ref, and assign it to "cdkDrag"
2. TS: call the method on this ref

[image: html]

[image]